# Typescript Same generic in two interface properties, require same type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm defining the following interface:

```
interface I<T>{
 foo: T
 arr: T[]
}
```

Then I create an identity function using the interface:

```
const fn = <T>({foo, arr}: I<T>) => ({foo, arr})
```

Later, when I call the function, I was expecting typescript would flag this as an error:

```
const res = fn({
 foo: {a: 'a', b: 'b'},
 arr: [{c: 'c'}],
}) // {a: string, b:string} !== {c:string}
```

But it does not.

So my question is, how can I assert that the types of `foo` and each element of `arr` are required to be of exactly the same type? meaning that I would only be able to call `fn` like this:

```
const res = fn({
 foo: {a: 'a', b: 'b'},
 arr: [{a: 'hello', b: 'world'}],
}) // T = {a: string, b: string}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I see that in your example, the type T is inferred to be `{a: string; b: string; c?: undefined;} | { c: string;a?: undefined; b?: undefined;}`. Due to the possible union type, TS doesn't complain.

Answer (score 1):

try this , using only one generic in func will union type

```
interface I<T, U> {
  foo: T
  arr: U[]
}

const fn = <T, U extends T>({ foo, arr }: I<T, U>) => ({
  foo,
  arr,
})

const res = fn({
  foo: { a: 'a', b: 'b' },
  arr: [{ c: 'c' }],
}) // error

const res2 = fn({
  foo: { a: 'a', b: 'b' },
  arr: [{ a: 'a1', b: 'b', c: 1 }],
}) // won't error , but ok, since type is safe
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to make it so that the type of `arr` must match what is specified in `foo`:

```
interface I<T, U extends T=T> {
    foo: T
    arr: U[]
}

const fn = <T, U extends T=T>({ foo, arr }: I<T, U>) => ({ foo, arr })

const res = fn({
    foo: { a: 'a', b: 'b' },
    arr: [{ c: 'c' }], //now flagged as error
})
```

Other than using `fn` as shown above (inferring all the types automatically), you can also specify a parameter like `fn<SomeType>` which will restrict the type of `foo` that can be passed.
(Here, it's ok to specify only one template parameter, because when U is not specified explicitly, `U = T`, so it will give `fn<SomeType,SomeType>`)